# Non-symmetric singular matrix with index 1

Tags: matrices

> The index of a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the smallest nonnegative integer $k$ such that ${\rm rank}\ (A^{k+1})={\rm rank}\ (A^k)$.

I am looking for a singular matrix with index 1. Is it possible to construct such type of matrix? Also, it should be non-symmetric.

Comment: What is the index of  a matrix?

Comment: Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. The smallest nonnegative integer 'k' such that $rank(A^{k+1})=rank(A^k)$, is the index of $A$.

Comment: Thanks! I think sigmabe gave an appropriate example.

Answer (score 1):

Take a $2\times2$ matrix:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&&b\\c&&d\end{pmatrix}$$
For $X$ to be singular, you need that $\det(A)=0$, that is $ad-bc=0$. In that case, $rank(A)=1$ (assuming there is at least one nonzero element, of course). Moreover, $\det(A^2)=(bc-ad)^2=0$, which again reduces to $ad-bc=0$ and $rank(A^2)=1$.

Now you just need to try several values and solve for the rest of them. For instane, take $a=d=1$ and follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a [projector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29). For the case $n=2$ for example
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$